# Получение всех подстрок из html шаблона

Tags: javascript

У меня есть какой-то html шаблон, в котором присутствуют некоторые теги, имеющие следующие контсрукции: `<input placeholder="{{некоторый текст}}">`, `<p>{{некоторый текст}}</p>` и т.д.
Я пытался в js находить такие результаты и получился такой код:

```
    html = $('html').html();
    var regExp = /\{([^)]+)\}/;
    var matches = regExp.exec(html);
    alert(matches[1])
```

Код неподходящий, т.к. берёт результаты только между одинарными фигурными скобками, а не между двойными. К тому же, он берёт всё, что находится между самой первой и самой последней скобкой в результате поиска, т.е. берёт лишние теги, текст и остальное. Какой нужен код, чтобы можно было достичь получение всех результатов в виде массива?

Comment: `{{(.*?)}}` используйте нежадный поиск, а если нужны дойные скобки,то и пишите двойные. экранируйте только как следует.

Comment: а теперь код выводит только первое совпадение, а как можно получить все сразу?

Comment: Вот так `alert(matches[1])` выводит первое совпадение? А если `console.log(matches)` так, то что выводит в консоль?

Comment: @XelaNimed, тоже самое

Comment: добавь модификатор `g` в регулярное выражение

Comment: @Grundy `var regExp = new RegExp('{{(.*?)}}', 'g');` так же выводит только 1 результат

Comment: @НикитаКраснобаев, используй не `exec`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [String.prototype.matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

```js
var str = "{{first}} {{second}} aaa {{third}} bbb";
var regex = new RegExp('\{\{[a-z]+\}\}', 'g');
var itt = str.matchAll(regex);
for(const match of itt){
  console.log(match);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё хорошо